# Assetic and generating new filename every change

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, assetic

Hi i am using assetic in symfony 3. But i have problem my assets are defined like this:

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite' filter='?uglifycss'
        'assets/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css'
        'assets/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'
         ...
%}
```

In console run `php bin/console assetic:watch`

After change in css or js it will generate new file but with same name for example `ce9c2ef.css`.

But it is problem because after deploy, css file has changes content but no filename so all people see old css...

Q: How i can change generated file name every change in css?

There is options 'output='path/filename.js' in {% stylesheets %} but there i can't add `<?php echo $var; ?>` or `{{ var }}`...

UPDATE:

assetic config:

```
assetic:
debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    uglifyjs2:
        bin: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs"
    uglifycss:
        bin: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/uglifycss/uglifycss"
```

templating config:

```
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
```

### EDIT:

So i found solution PARTIAL solution:

To config add:

```
assetic:
    workers:
        cache_busting: ~
```

and after that, your file will looks like `ce9c2ef-d1e35a0_filename.css` in develop and `ce9c2ef-d1e35a0.css` in prod...

but in deploy you must **clear cache first** so you have 2 hashes first `ce9c2ef` still the same (I do not understand the point of existence) and second `d1e35a0` is changing so it finally resolving problem with browser cache....

But if you make changes in css, assetic:watch compile it, but page **loads old** files...!

**Worst bundle ever** i mean that changing filename is basic thing and on the internet is so many ways how resolve it and i was tryed one after another 1 day until i finally succeed...

Comment: Did you tried change the name on link tag? 
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}?v=2" lazyload/>
Notice the "?v=2". Regards

Comment: I am searching for auto generate because i don't want changing this every depoloy or every change in css

Comment: What does your `assetic` and `framework:templating` configuration look like in your `app/config.yml` file?

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 2):

When you're using assetic, one way to solve your issue is by giving your assets a version in your `framework:templating` section of **app/config.yml**:

```
assets:
    version: "%application_version%"
```

Then you can specify your version in your **parameters.yml/parameters.yml.dist** file:

```
parameters:
    application_version: 1.0.1
```

Then you can load your stylesheets or javascript like so:

```
{% stylesheets output='css/sites.css' filter='cssrewrite'
    'assets/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css'
    'assets/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'
     ...
%}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Now when you dump your assets, it will automatically append `?1.0.1` (or whatever version you are on" to the end of them.  For example, in production you would see the following:

```
<link href="/css/site.css?1.0.1" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
```

Note that there are different ways of doing naming strategies, and this can get tricky if you forget to update your assets version every time you make changes to your assets, but there are ways to improve upon that strategy.  This should get you up and running though.

If you notice I didn't manually specify the `uglify*` filters - you can have these automatically applied by putting this in your **app/config_prod.yml**:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        uglifycss:
            apply_to: "\.css$"
        uglifyjs2:
            apply_to: "\.js$"
```

Comment: thx for response but if i do this changes - add `assets_version` to parameters and config i get this exception: `Unrecognized option "assets_version" under "framework.templating"` Also i tryied move `assets_version` under `assets` in cofig file and add `base_path` (also under assets) and i am getting the same exception. (also trying clear cache)

Comment: Ah looks like this changed in newer Symfony versions...updated my answer

Comment: It look like it works only on images... But now are assets compile twice. First with old hash prefix and second with 'site' prefix and on develop is included old filenames

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by compiled twice.  Also I'd have to see how you are declaring the javascript files to see where that's going wrong.

Comment: Compiled twice means assetic create 2 css files 1 file is with name still the same and second is first filename + some changing hash...  But problem is if i editing some css it works wierd... One-two changes is working and after that it won't works i must delete all css files make another change and it works for while... Javascript files i am declaring in the same way as css but with only one filter so `{% javascripts filter='?uglifyjs2'` ... included files ... `<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>` ... `{% endjavascripts %}`

Comment: This answer work for `assets:install` but not for `assetic:dump`.